# Setting up an off-brand USB joystick

Tags: drivers, usb, joystick

I've just purchased an off-brand joystick "Esperanza", and I've been trying to set it up for the past hour.

Every single time I plug it in, the `xpad` module gets enabled. Which is for Xbox supported controllers but this controller is definitely not an Xbox controller.

In `lsusb`, the controller is even named as an Xbox controller:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
```

When I run `evtest` and select the controller, it doesn't recognize any of the key presses.

I've tried to see if it was even transmitting any data through the USB port at all. I enabled the `usbmon` module and ran:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u > /tmp/1.mon.out | tail -f /tmp/1.mon.out
```

(which logs ALL USB input) aaaand... Nothing. It only shows something when I plug the USB in or take it out, but nothing happens when I press some of the keys.

However, I might know why... When I run `cat /var/log/syslog`, it shows the following:

```
Apr 27 22:48:53 banana-pc systemd-udevd[24319]: Process '/usr/bin/jscal-restore /dev/input/js0' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 27 22:48:53 banana-pc upowerd[1615]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:2563:0575.0016
Apr 27 22:48:53 banana-pc upowerd[1615]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Apr 27 22:48:53 banana-pc upowerd[1615]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4
Apr 27 22:48:53 banana-pc upowerd[1615]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:2563:0575.0016
Apr 27 22:48:53 banana-pc upowerd[1615]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Apr 27 22:48:53 banana-pc upowerd[1615]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4
Apr 27 22:48:53 banana-pc kernel: [40974.817229] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc kernel: [40974.987630] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=028e, bcdDevice= 1.10
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc kernel: [40974.987635] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc kernel: [40974.987638] usb 1-4: Product: Controller
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc kernel: [40974.987640] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: SHANWAN
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc kernel: [40975.007946] input: Microsoft X-Box 360 pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input55
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 36: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4"
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 36 was not an MTP device
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc systemd-udevd[24329]: Process '/usr/bin/jscal-restore /dev/input/js0' failed with exit code 1.
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc upowerd[1615]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Apr 27 22:48:54 banana-pc upowerd[1615]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:02:00.3/usb1/1-4
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**
So, I thought perhaps the issue is because of the `upowerd: unhandled action 'bind'` thing. But my Akai MPK Mini displays the same messages, yet works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the solution turned out to be incredibly simple.

All this time something was disabled in the controller. I held the "ANALOG" button for 5 seconds and it magically started working. This wasn't documented anywhere...

So in case you're facing the same problem and you're using a cheap Chinese joystick, give this a try. Who knows, maybe it'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that jscal error popping up there, taking control of the device

Looking online, jscal-restore is Ubuntu's joystick configuration setter, and it seems to be started by a udev rule when it's plugged in. It could be that you need to [set the configuration up](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/jscal.1.html) before jscal-restore will run without failing.

It's also worth making sure that when plugged in, `/dev/input/js0` is pointed towards a hardware device in `ls -lga` as that's what jscal is trying to run on. You may have to make it a symlink to the actual hardware to trick it

It looks as if it's set as a udev-rule as well, so if this software is clashing with your hardware you could try finding and disabling the udev rule for it and seeing if Linux handles it fine vanilla, without jscal, or worst case uninstall it and see if an alternative works

Comment: `ls -lga /dev/input` shows the following for `js0`: `crw-rw-r--+  1 input 13,  0 Apr 28 09:38 js0`. I guess that 0 (After input 13) means it's not poin ted towards a hardware device? How would I symlink it? What would I symlink it to?

Comment: The c part at the beginning of the permissions string is the important part, shows it's recognised as a character device file not a regular file, and it is being populated so it's not that missing. The file is owned by the `input` group though, have you made sure your user is a member of that? (`usermod -a -G [User] input`)

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same error when I tried to connect a MicroSoft XBox 360 wireless controller.
Usually I could find the joystick device in `/dev/input/js0`, but it suddenly disappeared.

In `/var/log/syslog`, I found these errors.

```
Feb 15 16:05:06 dudley kernel: [  631.355686] input: Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11.2/1-11.2:1.0/input/input29
Feb 15 16:05:06 dudley systemd-udevd[3040]: Process '/usr/bin/jscal-restore /dev/input/js0' failed with exit code 1.
```

- Rebooting the PC did not solve.
- Unplugging and plugging the wireless receiver (USB) did not solve.
- Rebooting the controller by removing and reinstalling the battery and then restarting it by holding the analog button for some seconds did not solve.
- Finally, **I could solve this by pairing the receiver and the controller**.